# Streaming POST large request in Pylons

Tags: python, post, pylons, wsgi

I am working on a Pylons 1.0 project using apache with mod_wsgi.  Ineed it to work with large POST and GET requests. For the GET requests I can just take the data source (file on disk usually) and read it and yield to the Pylons layer to stream the data back to the user. I also know that I can use mmap with urllib2 to stream data requests to other services.

However for POST requests to my service how do I stream the request to disk so as to not overwhelm my memory usage when someone uploads a large file? I see req.body_file which may indicate Pylons is already doing this for me. Anyone know if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylons uses the [WebOb project](http://webob.org/) to supply the request and response objects, and it handles file uploads efficiently.

File upload handling internally is actually delegated to the python stdlib [`cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), which uses temporary files to handle uploads.

Ultimately, this is also due to the underlying [WSGI standard](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), which specifies that the request input is a stream.

Comment: Awesome!  I suspected that might be the case as I looked through the WebOb documentation but good to confirm. Thanks for the info.